# Get Users of Multitenant Enterprise Application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, claims-based-identity

I registered a mutitenant application in my tenant. This application is shown in both App Registration and Enterprise Application menu in my tenant as I registered it. And I'm getting the users by using Graph Api.

My Question is : - I provided my multitenant application to other tenants and I wanted to get all the users of that tenant who get to registered in my application. How do we get the other tenant's user if they registered in my multitenant application?

Comment: What is "who get to registered in my application"? You are using Azure AD B2C and they register to your Azure B2C tenant?

Comment: Hi, do you have a chance to look into my answer? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not an B2C scene, I assume that the other tenants have added your multi-tenant application.

Then you should implement [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) with an account of the target tenant. And use this account to query the users with Microsoft Graph API: [List users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

You can't use an account of your tenant to query the users of other tenants unless you add your account as a guest into other tenants. But this is another scene, it doesn't require muti-tenant application.

Comment: I got this. And now I'm able to get the Users of other tenants using my multitenant applications.

Comment: I have one more query. I have assigned some roles in this multitenant application and these roles are available to other tenants also, other tenants are able to assign roles to their users and they also enabled the User assignment required to Yes so that only those users who have the roles are able to login into my multitenant application. I wanted to ask you: How to get users's roles i.e which user assigned which roles? There is no property for user in User Entity.

Comment: @Siddharth If you have assigned app roles to users, once the user logs in, you'll get their roles in a claim of id token:

`{
  "roles": ["{your custom app role}"]
}`. You can refer to this sample code: https://joonasw.net/view/using-groups-vs-using-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps.